# Response.Redirect is set to another page, but goes through Page_Load on current page again

Tags: c#, .net

I have a page that has...

```
Page_Load(){
  if (Session["UserName"] != null){
     //code for security questions.. i have to go into this logic on every postback to check the security answer.
  }
  else{
    //sends to a page i don't want it to go to
  }
}

method(){
 ...
 Session["Username"] = null;  //if it reloads the page_load from this page, it sends it ot a page i don't want it to go to.
 Response.Redirect("nameofpage.aspx");
}
```

The problem is that it does not go straight to the new page. It is going  through the Page_Load of this page again, and I need it to go to "nameofpage.aspx". Is there a way to send it to the next page without using Server.Transfer?

Comment: You've got it surrounded in a try catch right?

Comment: hmm i will try that. maybe it will catch an error.

Comment: Actually nevermind I found out your problem.

Comment: it caught an error, but it is still reloading the same page after the response.redirect and I can't use !Ispostback because when there are legitimate security question postbacks, it needs to go into the code. *im debugging someone else's code. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was a lousy javascript _dopostback on the front side causing multiple postbacks. :(

*bangs head on desk and mutters... *other ppls code*

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to check if a the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.

Comment: the page.ispostback property would work to prevent this, but it is a security question page and I have to go into the logic on every postback.

Comment: If you can't use `IsPostback` maybe you can call `Response.Redirect("nameofpage.aspx")` from your `method()` and then set `Session["Username"] = null` during `Page_Init` of your `nameofpage.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is the redirect does a post back. You can use the function `IsPostBack` to check to see if it's the first time a page is loaded or if its being run on postback.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the page is doing a `postback`. That is why your page is firing twice I believe. In your code you should do:

```
if(!this.IsPostBack)
   //continue with code
else
   //something else
```

Also do a check on your #page directive and be sure that `AutoEventWireup="true"` isn't there. This typically is a root cause of the postback issue or why `page_load` would be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

If `IsPostBack` doesn't helps, check these values too; it should be enough to figure out what you need to do.

```
bool PostBack = Page.IsPostBack;
bool CrossPagePostBack = Page.IsCrossPagePostBack;
bool CallBack =  Page.IsCallback;
```